# how to format a single html a href text to have multiple css properties (two different font families)

Tags: css, font-family, graphical-logo

I want to create a logo with CSS using two different font families on a single a href

For example

```
<style>
    a#logo{
        "LogoWith" - font-family:sans;
        "TwoFontFamilies" - font-family:Ariel;
    }

</style>

<a id="logo" href="#">LogoWithTwoFontFamilies</a>
```

I know the CSS I wrote is wrong. I just can't seem to find a solution to applying two different font-families on a single string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use spans in the middle of your `a` tag:

```
<style>
   a#logo .oneFont { font-family: sans-serif; }
   a#logo .twoFont { font-family: Arial; }
   a#logo .redFont { color: red; }
   a#logo .blueFont { color: blue; }
</style>

<a id="logo" href="#">
    <span class="oneFont">LogoWith</span>
    <span class="twoFont">TwoFontFamilies</span>
    <span class="redFont">AsManyAsYou</span>
    <span class="blueFont">WantToUse</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do the job. Although it does create a small space between the words. Can't figure out how to make it look like its a single string...

Comment: If you don't want a space, keep you spans on one line with no whitespace in between:
`<span class="oneFont">...</span><span class="twoFont">...</span>`